# Track user journey with MS Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

With Application Insights you can add a user(name) and session details. Is there an option to get the complete events of a journey during a session for a particular user.
Looking to have this as a kind of support when a user calls in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the Diagnostic Search pane, and you drill into a specific event (like a Server Side request), there will be an option at the very bottom titled "All telemetry for this user session".  You can click it, which starts a new Diagnostic Search for that particular user session (for whatever the definition of a user session might be, perhaps the IIS SessionId I'm not positive).  It does appear that this will collate both server side requests and client side page views.

We store the AD domain username as a custom "Username" property on all telemetry (both server side and client side), so with that once we find an event for the user we care about there is a corresponding "Diagnostic Search" in the "..." context menu for that custom property, which will then do a Search for all telemetry with the matching custom property value, thus allowing us to see all telemetry related to that user.  its very nice for the scenario you are describing!